# Node.js Alert Causes Crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, alert

I'm trying to create a node.js app and

```
alert('Sample Alert');
```

is causing my program to crash. Node says

> ReferenceError: alert is not defined

and then quits. I can use the `alert` function when running javascript on a regular html page, so I'm at a loss to understand why this is... Is this a separate module that I have to use with node.js?

Comment: anything outside [this](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)  is not regular javascript

Comment: @Esailija - Technically regular JavaScript *should* have `alert` since JavaScript is a branch of ECMAScript normally implemented in browsers. What you meant was probably ECMAScript.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `alert()` function is a property of browser `window` objects. It is not really part of JavaScript; it's just a facility available to JavaScript code in that environment.

Try `console.log("Hello World");`

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make any sense, really. Your server code can send an error out as part of a response to an HTTP request, and then, in turn, some **separate** JavaScript code running in the client browser can present an alert. That'll have very little directly to do with the JavaScript code that comprises your server-side application.

Answer (score 12):

`alert()` function is only available when you execute JavaScript in the special context of browser windows. It is available through the `window` object.

Node.js is not intended for writing desktop applications (directly). It is mainly intended for writing server-side JavaScript applications. You can use following frameworks/packages (and many more) if you want to develop true desktop applications.

- [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)
- [NW.js](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) (previously, node-webkit)

  > NW.js is an app runtime based on `Chromium` and `node.js`. You can write native apps in HTML and JavaScript with NW.js. It also lets you call Node.js modules directly from the DOM and enables a new way of writing native applications with all Web technologies.
- [AppJS](http://appjs.com/)

  > Available as an standalone distributable and an npm package

---

Meanwhile, you can use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to output a message in Node.js.

```
console.log('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

While these answers are "correct", as there is no alert function available outside of the browser, there's no reason you can't create one and then use it:

```
node -e "function alert(x){ 
            x === 'undefined' ? console.log('undefined') : console.log(x); return; 
         }; 
         alert('x'); alert();"
```

results:

```
x
undefined
```

Then you might not need to change your existing code or example or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need code to wait for a key. Here's a start:

```
process.stdin.on('char', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk + 'got?\n');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

alert function is for browsers. means front end..in nodejs for printing in cmd or bash you should use this one..

```
console.log("Sample alert");
```

you can print any variable or constant here... for printing variables just remove quotes

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` property is only allowed by browsers, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since things like DOM and alerts are made for your browser to execute, you cannot use them in your nodejs environment.
Use

```
console.log('Sample Alert');
```

or if you want to use DOM or alerts, follow-->

What you can do is, first make a separate .js file for your HTML file and then link those two...

Note: Make sure the path is right (For .ejs users, make sure to give a path relative to your public folder) and now you can use your alerts.

Hope this helps.....

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where it is documented but I have been using `global.alert()` in my `react-native` code. I am using it for debugging purposes because I am running an `Appium` test so I don't have access to the `console.log()` output.