# PLEASE help me with meteor method

Tags: methods, meteor, call

I have revised many times but I don't see the problem.
I get this error:

```
errorClass {error: 500, reason: "Internal server error", details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
```

Here's my code:

```
Meteor.call('addToBasket',
                function(error,result){
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                }
            );
```

And here the meteor method:

```
addToBasket: function(){
    alert('inside meteor method');
}
```

When I call the method I get the message from `console.log(error)`
I have other methods that work perfectly.

Do I have to subscribe a meteor the collection or something ??

Comment: Are you trying to use `alert()` on the server? Also, please make sure to have a [clear title](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, `Meteor method always throws error` could work. And make sure not to _actually_ ask for help here, that's why we're on SO in the first place! =)

Comment: Change your alert to console.log and you get a success message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use alert function in method because alert is not defined on the server. If your method is shared for the client and server, you can use if Meteor.isClient:

```
addToBasket: function(){
    if (Meteor.isClient)
        alert('inside meteor method');
}
```

If your method is defined just on the server, use console.log instead of alert and see server console for the log.

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` will only work in the browser.

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618456/node-js-alert-causes-crash) explaining why alert doesn't work in node.js.