# How to alert in deployd server?

Tags: deployd

```
var match = this.FBUniqID; alert(match);
```

When I run the above code in `deployd` console, it gives an error

> { "message": "alert is not defined", "status": 400 }

How can I generate an alert message in `deployd`?

Comment: Hm, try to use `console.log(match)`

Comment: You cannot use `alert` inside deployd.`alert` is a JS function specific to browser window,whereas deployd is build on Node JS where those APIs are absent.Like @John_West  suggests use `console.log(match);`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/11618468/1566267