# Express route passing in javascript method and not just objects

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to pass in methods instead of just objects in an Express route?

For example, after redirecting to a specific route, I want to execute an alert function.

```
app.get(res.redirect('/', function(req, res){
   alert('this is an alert');
   });
);
```

console.log - seems to be ok, but other methods are not.

I have tried:

```
res.redirect('/');
alert('this is an alert');
```

same thing error: ReferenceError: alert is not defined

As, answered below that Alert is a Client side function and not a server side function:

Is there a way that I can tell the server side to pass some client side function after redirecting?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 4):

The reason this doesn't work is because node.js and express are on the server side. The alert function has to be executed from the browser as it is a property of browser window objects.

See [Node.js Alert Causes Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618456/node-js-alert-causes-crash)

Comment: Just to add more details: alert is a function of the *browser's* `Window` object. Node has no such `Window` object

Comment: Is there a way that I can tell the server side to pass some client side function after redirecting?