# Why does Naked execute the code incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

For some reason I don't understand, Naked executes js code with exitcode 1. I can't understand why this is a problem.

Please tell me what's wrong?

ps python script is on the server and loads the page from the html file, after which js should be executed and alert should display 2 messages.

### CODE:

Python:

```py
#!/Python380/python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs
import os
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())

f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/pages/minilib.html", "r", encoding="utf-8")
f = f.read()

print("Content-type: text / html\n\n")
print(f)

response = muterun_js(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'file.js')
if response.exitcode == 0:
    # the command was successful, handle the standard output
    standard_out = response.stdout
    print(standard_out)
else:
    # the command failed or the executable was not present, handle the standard error
    standard_err = response.stderr
    exit_code = response.exitcode
    print('Exit Status ' + str(exit_code) + ': ' + str(standard_err))
```

JS in file.js:

```js
var x = 10;
x = 10 - 5;
alert(x);
function greet() {
      alert("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

Python output:

```
Exit Status 1: b'"node" \xad\xa5 \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xa2\xad\xa5\xe8\xad\xa5\xa9\r\n\xaa\xae\xac\xa0\xad\xa4\xae\xa9, \xa8\xe1\xaf\xae\xab\xad\xef\xa5\xac\xae\xa9 \xaf\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xa0\xac\xac\xae\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xad\xeb\xac \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xac.\r\n'
```

### My output

[image]

### Error

through an online decoder received this error text:

```
is not an internal or internal command, executable program or batch file. \ r \ n
```

[image]

### NODE.js executes js file:

[image]

Comment: Maybe something to do with the `alert()` statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618456/node-js-alert-causes-crash

Comment: @Ouroborus, but `console.log` doesn't output anything either (((

Comment: Does it at least stop producing a failure?

Comment: It's returning a byte string, but I don't know what your default language is in order to decode it. It's not one of the english codecs. You'd do something like `response.stderr.decode('cp1250')`. (But your language isn't cp1250.)

Comment: @Ouroborus, no, everything is the same

Comment: @Ouroborus, look at the question. slightly supplemented it

Comment: Well, it can't find `node`. Is node even installed? Naked doesn't install that itself. See [A Simple Approach to Execute Node.js Scripts With Python](http://sweetme.at/2014/02/17/a-simple-approach-to-execute-a-node.js-script-from-python/): "Execution of these local JavaScript files is dependent on a local Node.js install on the system where the Python code is executed."

Comment: @Ouroborus, node.js I have installed. I will deal with your link

Comment: @Ouroborus, node.js executes js script, but nothing works through python (screen added to question)

Comment: @Ouroborus, any more ideas why this error outputs?

Comment: I'm not sure why python can't find node. Did you restart the shell you're running python in so that `PATH` is up to date? Looking at the docs for [`execute_js`](https://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html#Naked.toolshed.shell.execute_js), it doesn't look like it's configurable and those functions are just wrappers for the generic command execution functions. You may have to use [`muterun`](https://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html#Naked.toolshed.shell.muterun) instead and provide your own command.

Comment: @Ouroborus, And so, after talking with the developer, I realized what the problem is naked on windows 10. For some reason, the command is not running for me: `subprocess.check_output`. Because of this, only errors are displayed and the program does not even try to execute ...

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Good afternoon! Solved the problem by replacing `subprocess.check_output` with `subprocess.run` in `shell.py`. Now everything is work) Perhaps the solution is clumsy, but working

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `alert` with `console.log` as you are running it in NODEJS. This would definitely work. Also I think you don't need to have a long file path. Only `muterun_js('file.js')` would work too. I am getting below as output.

I changed the file as below.

```py
response = muterun_js('file.js')
if response.exitcode == 0:
    # the command was successful, handle the standard output
    standard_out = response.stdout
    print(standard_out)
else:
    # the command failed or the executable was not present, handle the standard error
    standard_err = response.stderr
    exit_code = response.exitcode
    print('Exit Status ' + str(exit_code) + ': ' + str(standard_err))
```

```js
var x = 10;
x = 10 - 5;
console.log(x);
function greet() {
      console.log("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

OUTPUT: -

[image]

Have you installed NODEJS? [You can install it here.](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: And nothing works for me( Everything is as it was, it also remains

Comment: look at the question. slightly supplemented it

Comment: i install node.js in 10 minutes give the answer. And yes, I'm silly XD

Comment: installed, but nothing changed ... You can see the confirmation of the installation in the added screenshot

Comment: Good afternoon! Solved the problem by replacing `subprocess.check_output` with `subprocess.run` in `shell.py`. Now everything is work) Perhaps the solution is clumsy, but working